# Copy a file from a docker image running on a Google Compute Engine VM to a Google Storage bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a Python 3.6 application within docker und would like to store the output file directly in a GCS bucket. What sounds obvious to me doing following within the docker image:

- Install gcloud in the docker image
- run the app
- switch to a 2.7 virtual environment, because gcloud requires this
- copy the file with `gcloud compute scp` to the bucket

But, how can I copy the file without switching to another venv?

Comment: By GCP VM do you mean GCE or GAE or something else?

Comment: Google Compute Engine

Comment: Please don't add your answer to the question itself. You can post it as answer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the file to GCS from your Python application or from a 2nd Python script, this is very easy - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-storage

Comment: that's indeed very easy - thanks. I included the code in an edit

Answer (score 2):

Solution - create file `gcpupload.py`

```
from google.cloud import storage

def main():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
    blob = bucket.blob('myfile.txt')
    blob.upload_from_filename(filename='/path/myfile.txt')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Run the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Need to create the api keys file through google cloud console
# API's and services -> credentials -> service account key
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=google-api-keys.json
python gcpupload.py
```